# "Operation is not valid for the state of transaction" when using EF6 context in TransactionScope across multiple threads

Tags: c#, transactions, entity-framework-6

Following code keeps crashing on: **The operation is not valid for the state of the transaction.**

I am using EF6.

Any idea why?

```
using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
{
    var threads = new List<Thread>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        var thread = new Thread((o) =>
        {
            using (var newTransactionScope = new TransactionScope((DependentTransaction)o))
            {
                using (var ctx = new TransactionDemoContext())
                {
                    ctx.Products.Add(new Product() { Name = "ProductName" });
                    ctx.SaveChanges();
                }

                newTransactionScope.Complete();
            }
        });

        threads.Add(thread);
    }

    threads.ForEach(w =>
    {
        var trancation = Transaction.Current.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption.BlockCommitUntilComplete);
        w.Start(trancation);
    });
}
```